# creating a separate directory for my subdomain in cpanel

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

i want to create a subdomain that the cpanel will create a separate folder outside of public_html

example:

I am creating subdomain `xyz` but it is stored in `public_html/xyz`
what I want it to save to `xyz.mydomain.com` which is outside public_html folder in the `/home/user` root folder like how hostgator cpanel does... is it possible to change the location??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have the Document Root of your subdomain outside of your public_html directory.

You can navigate to:

cPanel -> Subdomains

... there you will see a column called "Document Root" - this is the directory that your subdomain will be "loaded" from

You can change that to another directory, for example if you place

/subdomain.com

in there you will create a folder /home/$USER/subdomain.com which will be your subdomain's Document Root

Comment: i did so, but it makes a sub directory inside public_html folder. example if i want to make a subdomain, called test, link: test.mydomain.com, inside my public_html i will find test.domain.com

Comment: In this case I believe that your hosting provider doesn't allow subdomains outside of public_html, this is usually a setting in WHM:

WHM -> Tweak Settings -> Restrict document roots to public_html

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't change it in your self, you should ticket to the host manger provide your service, because it changes in WHM